# Can't read lines between two patterns using AWK

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to read an openvpn status log to get connected users. I've tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or), but no luck.

Here's my file:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Mon Jul 13 10:53:46 2020
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
user123,8.9.10.11:24142,143404433,5616022,Mon Jul 13 10:09:31 2020
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
192.168.1.2,user123,8.9.10.11:24142,Mon Jul 13 10:53:45 2020
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,1
END
```

I want the lines between "Common" and "ROUTING", e.g:

```
user123,8.9.10.11:24142,143455713,5682214,Mon Jul 13 10:09:31 2020
```

Using this:

```
awk '/Common/{flag=1;next}/ROUTING/{flag=0}flag' /pathtomylog/openvpn-status.log
```

I get:

```
user123,8.9.10.11:24142,143455713,5682214,Mon Jul 13 10:09:31 2020
192.168.1.2,user123,8.9.10.11:24142,Mon Jul 13 11:00:36 2020
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,1
END
```

Any help appreciated.

Edit: The following code worked perfectly. The issue was the 2nd instance of `Common`.

```
sudo awk '/ROUTING/{flag=""} /^Common/{flag=1;next} flag' Input file
```

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Poz 'Common Name.*\n\K(.|\n)*(?=ROUTING TABLE)' file` or `grep -Poz '(?<=Connected Since\n)(.|\n)*(?=ROUTING TABLE)' file`

Comment: @Cyrus thanks this works as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/ROUTING/{flag=""} /^Common/{flag=1;next} flag' Input_file
```

***Why OP's code didn't work:*** First flag is getting set by line starting with `Common` and then again its getting set by string `Common` which is coming after `ROUTING` too by which variable `flag` is getting set again and then its NEVER get unset because `ROUTING` is NOT found after 2nd `Common` hence its printing all lines from there. So I changed regex which is looking for `/^Common/` which will not that match other line after `ROUTING`.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
/ROUTING/{        ##Checking if a line starts from string ROUTING then do following.
  flag=""         ##Setting flag value to NULL here. Since we want to STOP printing from here onward.
}
/^Common/{        ##Checking condition if a line starting from Common then do following.
  flag=1          ##Setting variable flag to 1 here.
  next            ##next keyword will skip all further statements from here.
}
flag              ##Checking condition if flag is SET then print current line(since no action mentioned so by default printing of current line will happen) here.
' Input_file      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I didn't even notice the second instance of `Common`. Great explanation.

Comment: @NonSequiter, your  welcome, glad that I could help you. Keep learning and keep sharing on this great forum cheers :)